# Cannot trigger function on Vuetify v-alert close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, alert

I am trying to call a function when a Vuetify `v-alert` is closed. Nothing I have seen in the docs covers it. As you can see in [the codepen example](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=101), there is a `dismissible` attribute which is used to add the ability to close the alert. But nothing I have tried allows a function to be called at the same time.

I have tried several regular Vuetify ways to achieve this such as,

`v-on:onclick="func()"`,
`v-on:click="func()"`, and simply `@click="func()"`, but it seems that a function cannot be called from a v-alert.

Note that I want to keep the `dismissible` attribute that smoothly removes the alert automatically when the close icon is clicked. I don't need to call a function to remove the alert itself, but to do something else after the alert is removed.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@input` on the `v-alert` element:

```js
<v-alert @input="foo">
```

`foo` will be called when the [x] is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify provides the `close` slot specifically for this use case. From the slot you call any method, and the scoped `toggle` method to close the alert.

```html
<template v-slot:close="{ toggle }">
  <v-btn @click="closeAlert(toggle)">Close</v-btn>
</template>
```

```js
closeAlert(toggle){
  toggle()
  console.log("alert closed")
}
```

See the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/bgtor/pen/VwWxxGY?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately, this seems to break the `dismissible` attribute. The button triggers the function, but the alert remains on the page. I would like to use the built in `dismissible` part of the alert and not extra buttons or slots if possible.

Comment: Do you call the “toggle” function¿ it seems to be working in the codepen. I don’t think there are other built-in options to accomplish the desired behavior

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify has a dedicated click:close event that's fired when the inbuilt close button specifically is clicked

just lisetn for the event on the alert usin:

`<valert closable @click:close="someFunction()"> Something happened </v-alert`